# Dojo/Angular Scope Issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dojo

I have a dojo module that has a ton of code in it and I wanted to be able to consume the functions inside the module. The module loads fine in my angular controller, but I have no way to consume the scope that is modified inside the controller in my view. How would I go about accomplishing this? Here is the code:

```
angular.controller('mapTestController', ['$rootScope','$scope', function ($rootScope,$scope) {

    require(['mapping/scripts/mapping'], function (mapping) {

        $scope.TestVar= "How do I access this in my view?";
    });

   $scope.map = {
      center: {
        lng: -122.45,
        lat: 37.75
      },
      zoom: 13

   };


}]);
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="AngularApp">
<div ng-controller="mapTestController">
    {{TestVar}} //this is blank
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really familiar with Dojo but the answer is likely to fall out of its scope.

```
require(['mapping/scripts/mapping'], function (mapping) {
    $scope.$apply(function () {
        $scope.TestVar= "How do I access this in my view?";
    }
});
```